# Haskell function that tests if a list has repeated (duplicate) elements

Tags: haskell

I have an exercise to do, however and since I'm new to the language, I can not find any way on how to do it.

I have this function "repeated" that's defined as such, given under this paragraph. It receives a list of Int and gives back a Bool value. It's supposed to check if a list has any repeated elements. If so, it's TRUE, if not, it's false. There is one extra: I have to define the function by recursion, so it has to be a recursive function. Would appreciate any help.

```
repeated :: [Int] -> Bool
```

EDIT1: So far, I've only managed to succeed with this amount of code

```
repeated :: [Int] -> Bool
repeated [] = False
repeated (h:t) =
```

Which gives me back the empty list, only. The rest, I've not been able to figure out so far...

EDIT2: Forgot about the singular lists... Also, possible answer?

```
repeated :: [Int] -> Bool
repeated [] = False
repeated [_] = False
repeated (h:t) = if elem h t then True
                             else repeated t
```

That's pretty much it. I've compiled the .hs and it worked perfectly. Thank you all for the suggestions and hints! :)

Comment: is this sorted or are you allowed to sort it first?

Comment: Carsten, I think it's sorted already. It doesn't specify, however...

Comment: @CarstenKönig What if the list is infinite?  You could still write this function to be terminating on an infinite list (provided it has duplicates), there's no need to sort it first.

Comment: It's probably easier to just use [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub): `repeated xs = xs == nub xs`?

Comment: @bheklilr exactly, what set me back was the fact that it could be an infinite list... However we have never used such lists, but the possibility might still be up, since we have to generalize...

Comment: @CarstenKönig aha - thanks for that one. Gotta correct it :P

Comment: @darkwing I would argue that it's just as easy to implement this for an infinite list as for a finite list using only functions in `Prelude`, no need to sort anything.

Comment: ``elem`` function may help.

Comment: @CarstenKönig Homework questions are OK, and this one is OK after editing.

Comment: It depends if it's 'repeated' elements or 'duplicate' elements. I would read 'repeated' as being 'elements next to each other which are the same', and 'duplicate' as 'elements anywhere in the list which are the same'. Repeated is the same problem as an arbitrary list of `Ord a` which has been sorted.

Comment: Since a one-element list can never contain duplicate/repeated elements, you can insert another case which is always False. Then you will only need to consider lists with two or more elements. And if you have two elements, you can compare them.

Comment: @MatthewWalton really good point - is this specified in your excercise (is there a example?)

Comment: @Baderous That tip was superb. Working on it now.

Comment: @MatthewWalton The exercise specifies "tests if a list has repeated elements"; I do think that by repeated it means duplicate elements, my language is really ambiguous :P

Comment: Alright guys, I think I've got it. Going to edit the possible answer onto the main post :)

Comment: @darkwing That is probably the solution your prof is looking for, but it won't work on infinite lists, unless the first element is duplicated!  Can you improve it?

Comment: `repeated [_] = True` looks very wrong.

Comment: @darkwing Shouldn't that be `if elem h t then True`?

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for noticing, was viewing this on both sides of the question!

Comment: As a side note, I would like to point out that this was a superb SO question.  You had a specific problem to solve, you participated in discussion promptly, edited your question to be more appropriate and for clarity, and added code as you started to solve the problem from hints.

Comment: @bheklilr A function like that for infinite lists can never return False, which makes it ever so slightly less useful.

Comment: @bheklilr I still don't know how to work with infinite lists, we still haven't learned it yet, so I'm presuming it's finite lists only :P

Comment: @n.m. True, but you can check more of an infinite list than just the first element if you suspect that the computation would complete with a `True`.

Comment: @darkwing I suggested a one element pattern match because it's useful for finding "adjacent-repeated" elements. If you are implementing "duplicate-anywhere" test, this case is not really useful (though it doesn't harm either). You can freely remove it. I suggest to write a separate function that tests just for adjacent repeated elements, and see what's different about it.

Comment: @bheklilr if I *know* there are duplicates I can just return True without checking anything. If I don't know for sure I risk non-termination. If one had to return the duplicate element itself, it would make sense.

Comment: @n.m. Wouldn't the "adjacent-repeated" one take less time to find out whether it had duplicates or not? Compared to the "duplicate-anywhere", I'm supposing this last one would take much longer to find them out (since the adjacent-repeated could stop somewhere in the middle of the code, as it would have found a duplicate?)

Comment: @darkwing That's correct. Your running time is O(n^2) as you are calling `elem` (which is O(n)) for each element of the list. The "adjacent-repeated" case could be easily made in O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to find if a list has any duplicates.  This means that you'll have to keep up with a list of elements that you've already visited so you can check this.  So first, write a function that checks if a single element exists in a list of already visited values:

```
alreadyVisited :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
alreadyVisited x [] = False
alreadyVisited x (v:visited) = ???
```

(Note: this is known as `elem` in Prelude, but you should be able to implement it yourself, and it's good practice)

Then you'll want to write the main function that loops over all elements in your target list, building a set of visited elements until it finds a duplicate.  Once a duplicate is found, the function can exit without checking the rest of the list.

```
-- Using a helper hides the fact that the visited list is needed
repeated :: [Int] -> Bool
repeated xs = go xs []
--                   ^--  initial visited list is empty
    where
        -- same base case that you came up with,
        -- an empty list does not have duplicate elements
        go [] _ = False
        -- The recursive step, think about what you need this function to do
        go (x:xs) visited =
            if alreadyVisited x visited
                then ???        -- If it's already visited, do what?
                else ???        -- Otherwise?
```

Here I've just set up the structure for you, you'll have to fill in the details yourself.  Keep in mind that this is *not* an efficient implementation, particularly because of how slow `alreadyVisited` will become as `visited` grows in size, but if you are interested in speed then you can swap out the visited list for a `Data.Set.Set`, which has much better lookup time.

Comment: if it is just about knowing if the list contains duplicates you can use the nub function in Data.List like so: `hasDup l = nub l == l` (nub removes all duplicates... so this will be true only if there are no duplicates in the list.)

Answer (score 6):

This is my approach for this (using Sets and comparing lengths)

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set -- From the 'containers' library

hasDuplicates :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
hasDuplicates list = length list /= length set
  where set = Set.fromList list
```

I'm using the [containers Haskell Package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers).

Answer (score 2):

Try using [nub](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub).

```
import Data.List
hasDuplicates :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
hasDuplicates xs = length (nub xs) /= length xs
```

Essentially, `nub` will return the unique elements of a list.

Comment: Since `nub` has a time-complexity of *O(n²)*, you may want to read [`nub` considered harmful](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2015/02/nub-considered-harmful.html) and consider using [`nubOrd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrd) from the package [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers).

Comment: The `Ord` constraint is redundant. `Data.List.nub` requires only `Eq`.